# Laravel Data Checking in Controller With Iteration

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I just want to check each row in the column if data exist or not. The Idea is very simple. I wrote PHP date iteration in Controller to be matched with my date field in table.

Here are my tables:

**tbl_user**

-id_user

-name

**tbl_timelog**

-id_user

-date

-time_in

-time_out

My Controller:

```
function PrintReport()
{
$totdays=30;

for($x=1; $x<=$totdays; $x++){
    $dates="2018-05-$x";

    $data_list=PrintModel::join('tbl_user','tbl_user.id_user' ,'=','tbl_timelog.id_user')->orderBy('tbl_timelog.id_user','ASC')->where('date','=',$dates)->get();

  }
  return view('report/index', compact('date_list'));
}
```

If date found/matched, I want to get some value (time in - time out), then I'd like to pass the result to the view.

```
<?php
foreach ($data_list as $value) {
echo "</br>".$value->id_user." ".$value->time_in."-".$value->time_out." 
</br>";
}
?>
```

But I dont know why the hell only last date (2018-05-30) is shown in view? Not each date in the field instead.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

this is because every iteration replaced the previous one .. what you can do is in your controller ..

```
$data_list = [];
for($x=1; $x<=$totdays; $x++){
    $dates="2018-05-$x";
    $data_list[] = PrintModel::join('tbl_user','tbl_user.id_user' ,'=','tbl_timelog.id_user')->orderBy('tbl_timelog.id_user','ASC')->where('date','=',$dates)->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is **don't** use queries insight **for loop** or **foreach loop**

```
function PrintReport()
{
  $totdays=30;
  $dates = [];
  for($x=1; $x<=$totdays; $x++){
    $dates[] ="2018-05-$x";  
  }

  $data_list= PrintModel::join('tbl_user','tbl_user.id_user' ,'=','tbl_timelog.id_user')->orderBy('tbl_timelog.id_user','ASC')->whereIn('date',$dates)->get();

  return view('report/index', compact('date_list'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make one array of all your date and then check the array value by [where-clauses whereIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)

My suggestion is if you want to get the result on base of start date and end date of month then avoid the loop

```
$start = new Carbon('first day of this month');
$firstDate = $start->format('Y-m-d');

$end = new Carbon('last day of this month');
$lastDate = $end->format('Y-m-d');

->whereBetween('date',array($firstDate,$lastDate))
```

If you want to get result of sepcific month then you use whereMonth() and whereYear Function

```
->whereYear('date', $year)->whereMonth('date',$month);
```

With your query

```
$year = '2018';$month = '5';
$data_list= PrintModel::join('tbl_user','tbl_user.id_user' ,'=','tbl_timelog.id_user')->orderBy('tbl_timelog.id_user','ASC')->whereYear('date', $year)->whereMonth('date',$month)->get();
```